Static Equilibrium of Rigid Bodies
When we talk about the idea of static equilibrium in engineering mechanics we consider the idealized case of a body which is a rigid body, meaning it cannot deform. Then we solve for the 3 equilibrium equations and find the moments and forces in the supports. For the sake of this question let's consider the cantilever beam case. I am curious as to why we do not consider the beam that can deflect or bend under these loads. Why do we always consider the ideal case of the rigid body beam? Is it because the beam that can bend violates the static equilibrium somehow? Additionally, in the cantilever beam case, the support is constraining all x,y, and rotation z motions. But technically if the beam is allowed to bend then the endpoint is allowed to displace from its original position. Does that mean that it's not constrained then and it's not in equilibrium?

Consider the case of a mass on a spring with the other end fixed. It certainly has a static equilibrium, but flexibility is part of the solution. It just depends on what you are trying to achieve.

We select the level of complexity of the analysis at a lever that is most sensible for the utility and scope of that analysis.
We expand the depth of our investigation where it is warranted.
Not only do we investigate the deformation of members and supports under the loads (such as in indeterminant structures), but we also investigate the thermal expansion of members, such as in large buildings or bridges, the natural frequency of structures for dynamic loading or seismic loading, fatigue under reciprocal loading, and creeping under prolonged loading.
We have to consider the geometry of a building when we design for seismic or wind loads.
We consider the behavior of a building in natural disasters such as hurricanes, and we have to study for a sensible collapse mechanism under extraordinary catastrophes such as a major fire or explosion to buy valuable minutes for the occupants to exit the building before it crashes.

Because a deflecting beam requires another level of complexity in the calculations.  We don't always disregard bending, we just do in the ME2020 Strength of Materials class (seems to have been renamed since my time to Mechanics of Materials)

Simple answer could be that all of the models are wrong, but some of them are useful. This is true almost in any field, but it is quite apparent in engineering. Even the idea of static equilibrium cannot ever be precise, because things just are not static. But it is very accurate for many cases, which makes it very useful.
Rigidity of the bodies is another simplification like this. Many structures are so stiff, that any deformation that would considerably violate the "rigid" assumption also leads to failure of the structure. This combined with the fact that it is quite easy makes static analysis with rigid body assumption quite useful.
If you need to take deformation into account, the next level is linear elastic analysis, where relation between load and deformation is assumed to be linear. Although that is not strictly true, you can get more precise results than from rigid body analysis (at the cost of increased complexity of the analysis). The last level would be nonlinear analysis, where you can take into account all sorts of effects like large deformations, nonlinear material models like elasto-plastic or hyperelastic.
So we do not always consider the ideal case of the rigid body beam. And the beam can be in equilibrium even after deformation (nonlinear analysis required here for general case).

But if you assume the deformation of the cantilever beam to be in a linear elastic region under applied load with certain degree of bending, is it still in static equilibrium or not?

I think you have it the other way around. First you need to assume it is in static equilibrium, which then gives you relations between loads and reactions. If you want the static equilibrium to be correct also in the deformed state, the problem becomes nonlinear. In general, you would need to do some iterative calculations to get an answer with required precision.

Then that means that the static equilibrium condition would be valid(for the linear domain) in the case that the beam is undeformed under the applied load which will give us the support reaction relations, right? And if the equilibrium needs to be evaluated when the beam bends then the nonlinearities come into play. Thank you for your response in advance.

Yes, that's how it works.

It is not like that. A deforming body would still be in equilibrium after it is done with its deformation. If not it means it would be accelerating per Newton's Law.
This applies to a deforming building or a bridge or your cantilever beam. Without equilibrium it is called a mechanism which works like a moving parts of a system. For mechanical engineers it may be good but for us a mechanism means a failed structure.
When forces act on a body we must find reaction forces. Whether the body is considered rigid or when we account for deformations. Without satisfying equilibrium we cannot do that. To find reactions while assuming rigid body is simpler however you can not do this for bodies with more supports than needed such as redundant constraints. In such case you need to consider deformations.
By the way in the case of end support of cantilever beam, right where the beam joins to the wall is still assumed as zero rotation even in problems where we consider deformations - at least for basic level problems.
